# RJ45 not working on my Toshiba Qosmio X500 Notebook

Tags: networking, usb-3, firewire, rj-45, expresscard

When I plug the RJ45 cable into the machine, running Windows 10, I get the message 
 `Unidentified network - No internet`

I do have a Wi-Fi connection to the router, so I am on the internet, but the machine is 9 years old and doesn't have a 5GHz radio, only a 2.4 GHz.  Before the RJ45 failed, the speed was greater.

Is there a workaround? Is there a way to connect RJ45 to one of the other connection points on the machine? There are USB2, Firewire, express card, and eSATA ports.  I have read on this site eSATA won't work.

Is there an adapter/converter/plugin to get USB3 from my connection points?

Comment: Are you using the right kind of cable? "Two wiring schemes–T568A and T568B–are used to terminate the twisted-pair cable onto the connector interface." aka as straight and crossover. Some old ethernet connection are not able to auto-switch between the two types.

Comment: It is quite reasonable to imagine that the RJ45 port itself has failed. Get a USB to Ethernet adapter and try that. These are inexpensive and readily obtainable from Amazon or like place

Comment: USB RJ45 Ethernet adapters are pretty common and relative cheap. As your PC most likely only has USB 2.0 port an 100MBit adapter would be sufficient.

Comment: @DavidPostill. Nothing wrong with the cable, works fine with my other PC, thanks - H

Comment: @Henrik Read my comment again. Newer machines can autoswitch between straight and crossover wired cables. Older machines cannot. Just because it works on a new machine does **not** mean the same cable will work on a 9 year old machine.

Comment: @John & Robert. I did start by getting a USB to Ethernet adapter. Nothing happened when I put it in, I then found the win10 folder on the mini-cd that came with the product and ran the install.exe - still nothing. And I have no idea what to or where to modify anything. thanks - H

Comment: Mini CDs (that I have used) were gone before Windows 10 came out. That may be the reason it is not seen/working. Try a more modern USB to Ethernet adapter.  They are always useful. Your machine may just be too old to do what you want.

Comment: @DavidPostill My place is wired with (I have just copied the data from the cable): CAT 6 U/UTP 250 MHz 4 PAIRS ISO/IEC 11801 & EN50173-1 & ANSI/TIA-568-C  2 ## 617 ## ... I found a old patch cable and tried that: Belkin CAT 5e #R7J304 (UL) 4PR 24AWG TYPE CM E129760-C ... No joy :-(

Comment: How is the Ethernet port looking physically? Are there bent pins? Do they still look like shiny gold pins?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Nothing bent, broken or missing

Comment: I know this may be a silly question, but have you checked to make sure that the adapter isn't statically set? While you are in the adapter settings, what is the the adapter reporting the line speed as when it's plugged in? Last but not least, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the adapter, or updating the drivers? You can also try running a live Ubuntu USB to rule out a windows problem.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I did run LINUX from a USB, same problem - it's not there. I think it is a hardware fault therefor the work around question.

Comment: **SOLVED** I got a TP-Link USB WiFi installed, I now have 5GHz compared to the built in (year 2011) 2.4 GHz. I noticed on my other PC that the wired and 5GHz speeds were similar. BIG smile - Henrik